# How to showcase key commits in git ideally without a full repo

Tags: git, diff

Like all of us I've done some key code commits which display my logic in following the `SOLID` paradigm, a well-written algorithm, etc..  I would like to showcase this in a similar interface (side-by-side) diff as you'd find on GitLab or GitHub.

Is there any way to do this (and not screenshots) that doesn't involve copying the entire repository?  Security is not an issue in this case and the client would not mind or object, but obviously copying a whole repo is not a good solution.

-- **EDIT** --
As it may be the case that GitHub is the only or best solution, perhaps a better question or direction might be this:

So `master` branch has commits/merges A through Z. My merges were J, M, and X.  Can I compress A through I, show merge of J > I, compress K through L, show merge of M > L, etc?

Comment: Is the project already hosted on github/gitlab/etc? Could it be? Then you just provide links to the appropriate diff url...

Comment: It is and can be.  But I just wondered if there's a way besides this.  See my edit above.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "compress A through I".  If you want to show the diff between J > I, you just care about the diff between those commits, which you get by linking to I.  A-H aren't relevant.  E.g., to show a feature I added to an project, I could link directly to [the commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6f2a9e42d14e61429af418d8038aa67049b3821).

Comment: Yes agreed, A through H aren't relevant, it's more of an effort to compress the overall history so one does not go browsing other commits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to set up a new repository for this purpose you can do what you want.  Let's say you have a repository with 10 commits:

```
$ git log --oneline
2c82196 this is commit 10
2bff8eb this is commit 9
7020be2 this is commit 8
0aea964 this is commit 7
c5d5fcb this is commit 6
c80dc97 this is commit 5
591367e this is commit 4
c2524c8 this is commit 3
3aa5e3a this is commit 2
33da02c this is commit 1
```

You want to highlight your changes in commit 5.  Just run an interactive rebase on the entire history:

```
$ git rebase --root -i
```

This will get you a pick list that looks something like:

```
pick 2d6696b this is commit 1                                                   
pick c5c7389 this is commit 2                                                   
pick c8cd62d this is commit 3                                                   
pick da0fb52 this is commit 4                                                   
pick 6ec5fac this is commit 5                                                   
pick 7508d6f this is commit 6                                                   
pick 6dede0f this is commit 7                                                   
pick 9e995b7 this is commit 8                                                   
pick 8b1299a this is commit 9                                                   
pick 44a32ee this is commit 10
```

Change `pick` to `squash` for commits 2-4:

```
pick 2d6696b this is commit 1                                                   
squash c5c7389 this is commit 2                                                   
squash c8cd62d this is commit 3                                                   
squash da0fb52 this is commit 4                                                   
pick 6ec5fac this is commit 5                                                   
pick 7508d6f this is commit 6                                                   
pick 6dede0f this is commit 7                                                   
pick 9e995b7 this is commit 8                                                   
pick 8b1299a this is commit 9                                                   
pick 44a32ee this is commit 10
```

...and  save the file.  This will squash commits 2, 3 and 4 into commit one, leaving you with the following history:

```
$ git log --oneline
9cec0a1 this is commit 10
b39ec3d this is commit 9
3578beb this is commit 8
1ce80b9 this is commit 7
2faaf79 this is commit 6
ff57ad9 this is commit 5
6a53018 this is commit 1
```

Now commit 5 has only a single parent.  You could do the same thing for subsequent commits. Again run:

```
$ git rebase --root -i
```

And then edit your picklist to squash all subsequent commits into commit 6:

```
pick 6a53018 this is commit 1                                                   
pick ff57ad9 this is commit 5                                                   
pick 2faaf79 this is commit 6                                                   
squash 1ce80b9 this is commit 7                                                 
squash 3578beb this is commit 8                                                 
squash b39ec3d this is commit 9                                                 
squash 9cec0a1 this is commit 10
```

This gets you:

```
$ git log --oneline
a7a03ba this is commit 6
01253c9 this is commit 5
a903311 this is commit 1
```

You could obviously also have simply used `git reset` to discard all the history after commit 5.

Comment: I accepted this because it was thorough and gave me a good pathway to proceed.  Thank you.